# Combining + operator with very specific selectors CSS

Tags: html, css

How do I combine the following selectors so that I can select the label that follows the checked radio button?

`+` does not work, I assume because it is operating on the specific element rather than the whole selector?

```
.container > .widget > input[type="radio"]:checked
.container > .widget > label

<div class="container">
  <div class="widget">
    <span><input type="radio" checked/></span>
    <span><label for="..."></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add some code to more clear understanding

Comment: Why don't you guys read the right side saying how to post the question? #Frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer not having your HTML.
But asuming the label is directly after the input.
You could use the [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+` to target the label.

```css
.container > .widget > input[type="radio"]:checked + label{color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="widget">
    <input type="radio" id="rdbtn1"/> <label for="rdbtn1"> My label</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
Now that you added HTMl I see that my assumption that the label was directly after the input was wrong. There is no way you can target the label if the input is selected using CSS with your current HTML markup.

If it's vital for your design to have the input and label to be wrapped in individual `SPAN`'s you can achive this using `Javascript`.

I suggest changing your HTML markup so that you can target the span using the `+`-selector.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot traverse to the parent in the CSS. Also, `<label>` cannot be contained inside `<span>`. You should ultimately change the way:

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
.container > .widget > label {font-weight: normal;}
.container > .widget > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="widget">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="theCheck" />
    <label for="theCheck">Label</label>
  </div>
</div>
```